# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Lieferadres' (T_VARIABLE), unlogischer Parseerror

Tags: php, mysql

That are the lines I have my problem with:

I checked for missing ; and so on but couldnt find a Solution..

Comment: your quotations, why dont you just bind them

Comment: Double quotes, singles quotes, double quotes.

Comment: And please escape your user input to avoid syntax errors or worse SQL injections.

Comment: If you are already using PDO, why don't you use prepared statements? It's generally safer and quite easy. See @rikesh's answer for an example.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Plus, you're still open to SQL injection. Whoever said using PDO would fix that, doesn't know about prepared statements. PDO on its own isn't an SQL injection fix. [**Use prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your query with double quotes,

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT K_ID FROM kunde WHERE Lieferadresse = '$Lieferadres'");
```

And rather use [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php),

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT K_ID FROM kunde WHERE Lieferadresse = :lieferadres");
$sth->bindParam(':lieferadres', $Lieferadres, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: I would actually suggest just adding a concatenation period like `Lieferadresse = \'' . $Lieferadres . '\''`   but yes Binds are the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot concatenation operator `.`

Also, any user inputted value that is going to be passed to SQL should be quoted with single quotes `'`.

As if user enters string over there, we insert the string without single quotes and it will cause SQL error.

Thus, corrected code:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT K_ID FROM kunde WHERE Lieferadresse = '" . $Lieferadres . "'");//Here the Error appeears
```